# how to write getLine function uses getc

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

i want to get line from a txt file with the function prototype

> int getLine(FILE* ptr,char* buffer);

but i have a stack problem...

```
int getLine(FILE* ptr,char* buffer){
int c;
while ( c = getc(ptr) != EOF && c != '\n'){
    *buffer++ = c;
    }
*buffer = '\0';
return 1;
}
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Do you hate parentheses? :) `while ( c = getc(ptr) != EOF && c != '\n')` -> `while (((c = getc(ptr)) != EOF) && (c != '\n'))`. How do you know `buffer` fits the characters?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to write parentheses around each expression. It is however necessary to write them around `getc` assign as `(c = getc(ptr) != EOF)` assigns `0/1` to `c` and returns equivalent boolean, while `(c = getc(ptr)) != EOF` return `true/false` according to what was read from `getc` to `c`.

Comment: It's more important to write `(c = getc(ptr)) != EOF` because of operator precedence.

Comment: whats wrong with my code?

Comment: It is, see my answer.

Comment: still not working...

Comment: char* strName ;
fp = fopen("students.txt","r");
if(fp == NULL){
 exit(0);
 printf("ERROR_2 while open txt file"); 
 }
  int a = getLine(fp,strName);
  printf("%s",strName);   
     fclose(fp);

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
c = getc(file) != EOF
```

you are assignig the result of the comparison

```
getc(file) != EOF
```

to `c`, it's like if you do

```
c = (getc(file) != EOF)
```

so you should add parentheses, because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so the corrected code is

```
while ((c = getc(ptr)) != EOF && c != '\n')
```

You should also, make sure you wont write past `char *buffer` passed to the function, so pass it's size, and iterate until you find `'\n'` or until there is no more room.

I would suggest

```
int getLine(FILE* file, char* buffer, size_t size)
{
    int    c;
    size_t count;
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return 0;
    while ((size < count - 1) && ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) && (c != '\n'))
    {
        *buffer++ = (char)c;
        count++;
    }
    *buffer = '\0';
    return 1;
}
```

you have to pass a pre-allocated buffer, and it's size so you prevent trying to add characters past the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

for calling the function i wrote need to be

> char strName[30];

and not

> char* strName;

so the buffer need to be pre allocated...
and calling by

```
getLine(fp,strName);
```

while fp is FILE*

```
int getLine(FILE* ptr,char* buffer){
int c;
while (((c = getc(ptr)) != EOF) && (c != '\n')){
    *buffer++ = c;
    }
*buffer = '\0';
return 1;
}
```